# What is the proper way to assign a jquery var name using a django var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do like so:

```
$counter-"{{ form.instance.id }}" = 0;
```

So that I can reference the unique counter for each form.  This line doesn't work though.  I also tried defining the var to keep it within scope of each form rather than global, but that wasn't working for me so I decided to settle on using the form id in the name.

What am I doing wrong in my definition?

logging in console shows the following error:

```
$counter-11 = 0
Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid left-hand side assignment
```

Comment: That should be throwing error in browser dev tools console due to invalid character in variable name. No errors showing in your console? If so you should mention them in your questions

Comment: Please clarify "a jquery var name using a django var?" I see no jQuery here

Comment: updated with console error

Comment: I think because I have $counter (with no id) defined elsewhere, my statement above is trying to subtract 11 from the $counter, rather than creating a new variable called $counter-11, which is what I want

Comment: You can use an underscore but not a hyphen in a variable name

Comment: yikes i feel dumb, thanks @charlietfl